# How to give the string value for character pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

How to give the string during runtime rather than pre initialization to a character pointer say `char *b;` through keyboard?

Comment: What do you mean? _string_ and _string literal_ are different things.

Comment: You can use `gets()`

Comment: @JafferWilson does not work in linux

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did not know that can you differentiate it briefly?

Comment: Better is to define your constant string in a resource and load it using LoadString() API function. If your project ever needs translation, this will make life easier.

Comment: @JafferWilson NO, NO, NO, you cannot use `gets`, `gets` has been dropped from the C library due to its insecurity, use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your string before compile and running your code with following syntax:

```
char * str = "Hello World";
```

by this way you define a constant string that change its content result in unspecific behavior. if you want you can allocate a string pointer and then use functions like `scanf()`, `fgets()` and ... in order to get its content from user or you can use functions like `sprintf()` in order to fill your string in your program. for example:

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
sprintf(str, "%s", Hello World");
```

If you want to have dynamic size string in runtime you can implement something like [C++ vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)#Vector)
and store your string in it.

Comment: There is no way without the pre allocation of the data right?

Comment: Yes you must allocate your string before you can using it but if you want you can implement something like vector by your self and then using it.

Comment: Vectors? can you briefly what they are and what for?

Comment: using char* = "string literal" takes away the constness of the literal.  Any attempt to modify the string will result in undefined behaviour. Use const char*="string literal" instead. Also, from a localization point of view, string literals are bad. Using resources in a separate module makes it easier to  switch between languages if requited.

Comment: thank your @Bart. I correct my statement about constant strings.

Comment: Hey can you guys differentiate strings and string literals briefly?

Comment: @psraganvesh check another answer for differences between strings and string literals.

Answer (score 1):

First, to clear things up a bit, as per `C11` standard, chapter §7.1.1,

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character.

and, as per §6.4.5

> A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in
>   double-quotes, as in `"xyz"`.

So, they are not the same.

However, to input a *string* from user, you can follow either of the below cases

- define a `char` array and scan the input (`scanf()`, `fgets()`).
- define a pointer, allocate memory and then use `scanf()` or `fgets()` to read the input from the user.

Comment: there is no way without the pre allocation of the data right?

Comment: When declared, a pointer has no storage of its own. To provide storage, you must allocate memory and assign the starting address for the memory block to the pointer. You can then copy to that new block of memory using the pointer. Think of a statically declared array `char buf[100] = {0};`. There `buf` holds the address to 100 bytes of memory. You could do `char *p = buf` and write to `buf` using `p`, or you could allocate for `p` (e.g. `p = malloc (sizeof *p * 100);`) and have the same amount of storage available. (it is up to you to free the memory you allocate).